# How to show set default value for DataGridViewComboBoxCell Value in winform?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a `DataGridView` having one `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and I have populated that ComboBox but after clear that `DataGridView` I have to set one default value for that ComboBox So please help me out.

Comment: The OP was last seen six years ago. Anyone know if there's a process for changing (wrong) accepted answers for zombie accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in `CellFormatting` event

```
void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) //Index of your DataGridViewComboBoxColumn 
      {
          e.Value = "Default Value";
      }
}
```

Comment: it works but gives me an error message with "value is not  a valid Boolean type " when i try to set its default value with a string. can u please help me with this? @Waqas

Comment: This gets called every time anything touches the cell, which causes the value to get set back to the default constantly. See my answer below.

Comment: this works but gives same value to all the rows on that column

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an ancient post, but hopefully, I can help some people avoid my confusion.

Using CellFormatting is a loser because it calls it every time anything touches the cell.  The result is that the value gets set back to the default constantly.

What worked for me was handling the DefaultValuesNeeded event like so:

```
private void OnGridDefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["Position"].Value = PositionEnum.Any;
}
```

This allowed me to set the default value, and lets the user change the value.

Comment: This works perfectly as I wanted. It set the selected value of combobox instead of just value. Thanks.

Comment: yup, this should be the answer, it only hits this event once, when adding a row. The format event is hit for every column any time you touch any column.