# How can I display the first value in the gridviewcombobox text by default

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind a combobox which in inside a datagridview using the following code and the binding is working fine but by defult the combobox text is empty. How can I display the first value in the combo box text by defult.My code is

```
DataTable dt1 = connection.SelectCommand("select jobcode from  jobsitemaster");
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells["jobcode"]);
      cell.ValueMember = "jobcode";
      cell.DisplayMember = "jobcode";
      cell.DataSource = dt1;
}
```

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this
         `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: DataGridViewComboBoxCell dosent have a property like selectedIndex

Comment: Please follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373854/how-to-show-set-default-value-for-datagridviewcomboboxcell-value-in-winform

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable dt1 = connection.SelectCommand("select jobcode from  jobsitemaster");
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells["jobcode"]);
    cell.ValueMember = "jobcode";
    cell.DisplayMember = "jobcode";
    cell.DataSource = dt1;

    // (not sure about the syntax)
    row.Cells["jobcode"].Value = dt1.Rows[0].Field<string>("jobcode");
}
```

Anyway, if all the cells have the same set of items, you may better use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn instead, and databind the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with dt1, and assign its Displaymember and ValueMember just as you do for all these cells. (Also specify the dataproperty name for all the gridview columns)

When you do this, use the datagridview.DataBindingComplete event. Loop through the rows in the DataBindingComplete handler, set the value of that cell in all the rows to dt1.Rows[0].Field("jobcode")